# Programmatically retrieve available file extension/format options

Tags: python, rendering, image, command-line

So as per the documentation, you can override the file extension/type setting for the Blender CLI: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html#format-options

> Set the render format. Valid options are: TGA RAWTGA JPEG IRIS IRIZ AVIRAW AVIJPEG PNG BMP
>
> Formats that can be compiled into Blender, ***not available on all systems***: HDR TIFF OPEN_EXR OPEN_EXR_MULTILAYER MPEG CINEON DPX DDS JP2 WEBP

In short, there are formats available for some Blender builds but not all. Is there a way to programmatically find that list of all file types available to the user, including ones just for their Blender build? I'd like to obtain the result in the console so I don't have to open up Blender (but I can settle for a Python script to run, ie `blender.exe -b -P script_to_print_all_formats.py`

I figured giving Blender CLI an incorrect format argument would give me a list of supported formats, but it doesn't.